# Can I review incoming changes in TortoiseSVN like in Eclipse before updating?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, review

The synchronize view of Eclipse is very nice to see incoming changes from everybody before updating my codebase.

Is there a similar feature in TortoiseSVN? I can only compare 2 revisions there, I did not find any functionality to compare my working copy (which is a mix of modified files and files from various revisions) with the HEAD revision easily!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the Check-For-Modifications dialog, then click on the "Check Repository" button.
That will show you which files are modified in the repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly!
Using Subversion instead of Eclipse helps me also to work around http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490769/eclipse-incoming-synchronization-view-shows-incoming-new-files-as-folders

Answer (score 4):

You can do show-Log -> right click on the new update and press 
"compare with working copy".

This will show you the difference between the updated file and the current one on your pc.

Comment: I think this is a better way than the official answer - for subtree it gives a clearer picture of the changes and it is also faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the log before you update. It shows which revision you're currently at (bold font) and what was committed later.