# Eclipse incoming synchronization view shows incoming new files as folders

Tags: eclipse, svn, synchronization, subclipse

I hope it is okay to ask for strange behaviour/bugs in Eclipse here.

When I use the Eclipse synchronize view with Subclipse, I used to see all incoming files from other developers very nicely with blue arrows pointing to the left. Double click was perfect to open the compare editor and review all changes.

For some time now, whenever a colleague adds a new file it shows up as an incoming new ***folder*** in my synchronize view! Even if I update it, I sometimes need to restart Eclipse to have this folder disappear from sync view (or sync a different folder and sync the root again). Also double click to open the compare editor is broken then (It's nice to see the new file, even though the left side of the compare editor is empty, but that does not matter to me)

Does anybody know why this happens? I tried all kinds of preference settings and could not find anything on google. I think I use Granny made or whatever they call it, I can't find a sane version number anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Does `Project -> Team -> Cleanup` help? Or maybe disconnect the project from the repo and checkout again, if the former wouldn't help?

Comment: I have not tried yet, but I think this is a general problem with a newer Eclipse version because a colleague confirmed it